# Show icons in option menu when using Theme.Holo

Tags: android-layout, android

When using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo` as the default theme for my activity, the icons defined in the menu xml are no longer visible in the options menu / action overflow (they were visible when using the old theme.)

How do I show the icons with `Theme.Holo`?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, to answer my own question: `Theme.Holo` does not show icons in the action overflow. So how come some of the preinstalled standard apps have menu icons? Because they're using the `Theme.DeviceDefault` theme, which is apparently different to Holo on my Samsung Galaxy S II.

Comment: Theme.DeviceDefault is supported for version 14 and above

Comment: I also noticed that `Theme.DeviceDefault` makes the icons visible in overflow menu on some Samsung devices (but not e.g. Nexus 7). What I'd like to know is how is that implemented, or how can I port that customisation to `Theme.Holo`, so that I get the icons to show up on all devices...